# Z-index doesn't work in Sub Navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, positioning, z-index

I have a problem where my z-indexes just won't kick in and I don't really get why.
I am not able to reposition the elements in the DOM, I need a purely CSS-based solution without any greater hacks

I have the following navigation:

```
<nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub test</li>
                    <li>Sub test</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S3XBD/1/

I packed it in a fiddle with the CSS to demonstrate my problem

my target is to get the **blue box** (Sub-Navigation) **under the green box** (Top level Navigation) in the exact same manner as demonstrated in the fiddle

Is there any way to fix my z-indexes or can someone point me to the mistake?

Thanks for your help

Comment: your blue box is under our green box, exactly as you describe. maybe a browser difference?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/S3XBD/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the z-index form the .wrapper element and change the z-index of the second ul to -1

```
nav .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background: green;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

...

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S3XBD/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your csss and removed hover as this is easy to fix: but the issue I believe you had was only in your positioning

```
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

nav .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background: green;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50 ;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 100 !important;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: block;

}
```

Just one thing more: User firebug to find out what it current style and you can modify it there on runtime. It also supports hover